# How can I get readxl::read_xls to read the first column of this dataset correctly?

Tags: r, excel, readxl

The first column is not being read correctly by `readxl::read_xls`:

```r
download.file("http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/bioenv.xls", "~/Downloads/bioenv.xls")
head(readxl::read_xls("~/Downloads/bioenv.xls",
  col_names = c("s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "Pollution", "Depth", "Temperature", "blank", "Sediment"),
  skip = 1))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 11
#>   s         a     b     c     d     e Pollution Depth Temperature blank Sediment
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <lgl> <chr>   
#> 1 2.79…     0     2     9    14     2       4.8    72         3.5 NA    S       
#> 2 5.40…    26     4    13    11     0       2.8    75         2.5 NA    C       
#> 3 8.19…     0    10     9     8     0       5.4    59         2.7 NA    C       
#> 4 3.89…     0     0    15     3     0       8.2    64         2.9 NA    S       
#> 5 2.60…    13     5     3    10     7       3.9    61         3.1 NA    C       
#> 6 4.59…    31    21    13    16     5       2.6    94         3.5 NA    G
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here's what the first few rows look like in the Excel file:

[image]

Comment: @dario Compare the first column in the actual Excel file and what is being read.

Comment: Oh, sorry misread column as row... P.S. What values do you get if you export the excel sheet as .csv? (just as a test, not as a solution to your question). It could be that what we see in the image and what is actually stored is not the same...

Comment: Interesting: I see that `A1` is empty in the spreadsheet, but with `names(ret <- readxl::read_xls("~/Downloads/bioenv.xls"))[1]` I get `"4.7999999999999998"`, and my entire first column is effectively the `Pollution` column shifted (`ret[1,1]` is `"2.79999"` and `ret[2,1]` is `"5.400..004"`). (I'm on R-4.0.5, `readxl-1.3.1`, win10.) I cannot find a combination of `col_types=` or `.name_repair=` that does not break this worksheet.

Comment: @dario I just discovered that it works fine with `xlsx::read.xlsx("~/Downloads/bioenv.xls", sheetIndex = 1)` so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Further, if I specify `sheet="bioenv"` or `range="bioenv!A1:K31"`, it fails to read the file. I wonder if this is either a semi-corrupted `.xls` file, a bug in `readxl`, or both.

Comment: (To the close-voter: yes, anonymous is fully justified. If you don't mind, please *justify your vtc* as "needs details/clarity", I completely disagree.)

Comment: I also encounter the same problem as you... Kind of unsettling that these numbers appear apparently out of nowhere.... **But** if I save the file it works as it should (LibreOffice Calc)

Comment: It's a Microsoft Excel 97-2004 `.xls` file... maybe too old for `readxl`?

Comment: Exporting as CSV produces also the correct data, and so does re-saving the file. i'd assume that this is an issue with the file itself (because a save operation fixes it)...